# a solution to the equations $p^{a-1}(p-1)=k(q-1)$ and $(k-1)q=p^a-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are two odd primes satisfying in the equations $p^{a-1}(p-1)=k(q-1)$ and $(k-1)q=p^a-1$ ($a$ is a natural number). Can we say that it only happens if $a=1$, $k=q$  and $p=q(q-1)+1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the notations used in Carl Schildkraut's comment:

$(p^{a-1}+2p-3)^2<N=p^{2({a-1})}+4p^a-4p^{a-1}<(p^{a-1}+2p-2)^2$, for $a>3$, which is not possible.

If $a=3$, then $N=p^4+4p^3-4p^2=p^2(p^2+4p-4)$ should be a square, which is impossible.

If $a=2$, then $N=6p^2-4p\equiv 2p^2\equiv 2$ (mod 4), which is not possible.

So we have $a=1$, $k=q$ and $p=q(q-1)+1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$kq-k=p^a-p^{a-1}\text{ and }kq-q=p^a-1,$$
so subtracting we have that $k-q=p^{a-1}-1$. Letting $k=t+p^{a-1}$ and $q=t+1$, we have
$$(t+p^{a-1})t=p^a-1.$$
This gives that
$$t^2+tp^{a-1}-(p^a-1)=0,$$
and for this quadratic in $t$ to have integer roots we require that
$$N=p^{2(a-1)}+4(p^a-1)$$
is an integer square. This is bad if $a\geq 4$, because then
$$(p^{a-1}+2p)^2=p^{2(a-1)}+4p^a+4p^2>N$$
while
$$(p^{a-1}+2p-1)^2=p^{2(a-1)}+4p^2-4p+1+4p^a-2p^{a-1}=N-\left(2p^{a-1}-4p^2+4p-5\right)<N$$
since
$$2p^{a-1}-4p^2+4p-5\geq 2p^3-4p^2+4p-5>0$$
when $p\geq 2$. If $a=3$, we require that
$$N=p^4+4(p^3-1)$$
is a square, but 
$$(p^2+2p-2)^2=p^4+4p^3-8p+4<N$$
while
$$(p^2+2p-1)^2=p^4+4p^3+2p^2-4p+1>N,$$
so that can't be. If $a=2$, we need
$$N=6p^2-4$$
to be a square. However, if $p=2$ this is false, and if $p>2$ then
$$p^2\equiv 1\bmod 8\implies 6p^2-4\equiv 2\bmod 8,$$
which can't be. So, the only solutions come from $a=1$, which are exactly the solutions you described.

Note that the only property of $p$ we used was that it must be odd, and even then only in the $a=2$ case. It's possible that a simpler proof can be given if the requirement that $p$ and $q$ are prime is more fully utilized.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in line 4. We have $t(t+p^{a-1})=p^a-p^{a-1}$.